# getting unassigned variable error on a variable that is assigned

Tags: c#

`userInput` is assigned so im not sure why I get error. I've already sifted through the similar questions, googled, binged and  didnt find what I was looking for. ps new to programming

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //declare variables
    int hours, minutes, seconds, remainder, userInput;
    const int SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60;
    const int SECONDS_PER_HOUR = 3600;

    userInput = getUserInput(userInput); //error

    hours = CalculateHours(userInput, SECONDS_PER_HOUR);
    remainder = CalculateRemainder(userInput, SECONDS_PER_HOUR);
    minutes = CalculateMinutes(remainder, SECONDS_PER_MINUTE);
    seconds = CalculateSeconds(remainder, SECONDS_PER_MINUTE);


    DisplayResults(hours, minutes, remainder, userInput, seconds);

}


//prompt the user to enter number of seconds
public static int getUserInput(int userInput)     
{
    Console.WriteLine("How about you enter a number of " +
                      " seconds and Ill see what I can do for you. ");
   return userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}

//this method takes in userinput and converts to hours if necessary
//userInput / SECONDS_PER_HOUR will be returned to CalculateHours
//in main and stored in the hours variable. same goes for the rest
//except DisplayResults
public static int CalculateHours(int userInput, int SECONDS_PER_HOUR)
{
    return userInput / SECONDS_PER_HOUR;
}
//this method takes userinput and gives a remainder to be used for minutes and seconds
public static int CalculateRemainder(int userInput, int SECONDS_PER_HOUR)
{
    return userInput % SECONDS_PER_HOUR;
}

public static int CalculateMinutes(int remainder, int SECONDS_PER_MINUTE)
{
    return remainder / SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
}

public static int CalculateSeconds(int remainder, int SECONDS_PER_MINUTE)
{
    return remainder % SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
}
```

Comment: new to posting here. It seems the top of my code got cut off for some reason.

Comment: You're passing `userInput` as an argument to the method `getUserInput`. At the point of the call, it is unassigned. It need not be a parameter, so remove it from the method and the call.

Comment: Which object is it telling you is not assigned to when using ?

Comment: Separate your code from the previous text by a blank line

Comment: thanks anthony I knew it was probabpy wrong but it was more of a last ditch effort after being stuck for a couple of hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problematic code:

```
userInput = getUserInput(userInput);
```

`userInput` is assigned *after* that statement, but think of it this way:

```
int tmp = getUserInput(userInput);
userInput = tmp;
```

Nothing has assigned a value to `userInput` *before* the method call. It's not clear why you're specifying a parameter at all, to be honest - you're not really using it. The code would be cleaner as:

```
int userInput = GetUserInput();

...

public static int GetUserInput()
{
    Console.WriteLine("...");
    return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Note how I'm declaring the variable at the point of first use - that's a generally good idea.  Additionally, it would be cleaner if you'd declare constants *outside* your method... and use those within your `Calculate*` methods (why would you want to parameterize the method by a constant?). So your `Main` method would be clearer as:

```
const int SecondsPerMinute = 60;
const int SecondsPerHour = SecondsPerMinute * 60;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int userInput = GetUserInput();
    int hours = CalculateHours(userInput);
    int remainder = CalculateRemainder(userInput);
    int minutes = CalculateMinutes(remainder);
    int seconds = CalculateSeconds(remainder);
    DisplayResult(hours, minutes, remainder, userInput, seconds);
}
```

(I'd suggest changing the order of the `DisplayResults` parameters to be more consistent too, along with a few other things, but that's probably enough for now.)

Comment: Hmm...I though you would leave the easier ones for the n00bs.

Comment: Thanks Jon. My textbook hasn't mentioned anything about declaring variables outside of Main yet but Im sure its coming sooner or later. But what you have said makes perfect sense to me thanks again.

Comment: I do have one more question Jon. Why SecondsPerHour = SecondsPerMinute * 60 instead of just SecondsPerHour = 3600?

Comment: @MilesLong: Because it's easier to understand that way, IMO. It's not too bad for 60 * 60, but by the time you get into "seconds per day" any particular constant literal stops being obviously correct. In production code I'd probably have a `MinutesPerHour` constant as well, and make `SecondsPerHour = SecondsPerMinute * MinutesPerHour`, but I thought that was overkill this time.